# Makeshift array of integers using counters

Tags: counters

I need to keep track of several counters. For that i use a bunch of counters and try to tie them inside a `\ifthenelse` hack producing a makeshift array of integers. I then later use the output of that hack to do a `\setcounter`. If I try to directly use `\thetypefirst` in a `\setcounter`, it passes without any hitch. However if it is hidden inside a bunch of `\ifthenelse`, it produces a missing number error.

MWE (actually non working):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{typezero} 
\newcounter{typefirst} 
\newcounter{typesecond} 
\newcounter{typethird} 
\newcounter{typefourth} 
\newcounter{typefifth} 
\newcounter{typesixth} 
\newcounter{typeseventh} 
\newcounter{typeeightth} 

% set a few values
\setcounter{typefirst}{11}
\setcounter{typesecond}{12}

\newcommand{\typeofdata}[1]{ % fails in an \setcounter statement
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{ \thetypezero }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{ \thetypefirst }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{ \thetypesecond }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{ \thetypethird }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{ \thetypefourth }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{ \thetypefifth }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{6}}{ \thetypesixth }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{ \thetypeseventh }{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{8}}{ \thetypeeightth }{%
    }}}}}}}}}
}

\newcommand{\tempcmd}{\thetypefirst} % works in an \setcounter statement

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{tmpp}
    \setcounter{tmpp}{\tempcmd}
    counter typefirst =\thetmpp \\
    \setcounter{tmpp}{\typeofdata{2}} %fail
    counter typesecond =\thetmpp \\
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some of the motivation behind your request? There might be a better way to go about this if we knew more.

Comment: In my question papers, there are various parts of it ... typically two or three (so eight types are more than enough for me). I need to keep track of the counts of questions of various types. This count is later used to produce either a solution of the q-paper or a fillable answersheet (for multiple choice questions). Since there will be other teachers (for whom just LaTeX will be too intimidating) too using this same format, I need to hide all the computing work in a preamble and present them an easy to use format. Ultimately I plan to tie it up in a ``documentclass`` for others to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use the numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{type0} 
\newcounter{type1}
\newcounter{type2}
\newcounter{type3}
\newcounter{type4}
\newcounter{type5}
\newcounter{type6}
\newcounter{type7}
\newcounter{type8}
\newcounter{type9}

% set a few values
\setcounter{type1}{11}
\setcounter{type2}{12}

\newcommand{\thetypeofdata}[1]{\csname thetype#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\typeofdata}[1]{\value{type#1}}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{tmpp}
\setcounter{tmpp}{\typeofdata{1}}

counter typefirst = \thetmpp

\setcounter{tmpp}{\typeofdata{2}} %fail

counter typesecond =\thetmpp

\end{document}
```

Comment: hmm.. I hadnt realised I could use the names of counters this way. great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to provide you with a more elegant proposal. This is something that works, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{typezero} 
\newcounter{typefirst} 
\newcounter{typesecond} 
\newcounter{typethird} 
\newcounter{typefourth} 
\newcounter{typefifth} 
\newcounter{typesixth} 
\newcounter{typeseventh} 
\newcounter{typeeightth} 

% set a few values
\setcounter{typefirst}{11}
\setcounter{typesecond}{12}

\newcommand{\typeofdata}[1]{ % fails in an \setcounter statement
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypezero}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{1}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypefirst}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{2}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypesecond}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{3}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypethird}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{4}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypefourth}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{5}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypefifth}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{6}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypesixth}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{7}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypeseventh}}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{8}}{\global\def\pfft{\thetypeeightth}}{%
    }}}}}}}}}
}

\newcommand{\tempcmd}{\thetypefirst} % works in an \setcounter statement

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{tmpp}
    \setcounter{tmpp}{\tempcmd}
    \typeofdata{2}
    counter typefirst =\thetmpp \\
    \typeofdata{2}\setcounter{tmpp}{\pfft}\thetmpp  \\
    \typeofdata{4}\setcounter{tmpp}{\pfft}\thetmpp  \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: my approach was not elegant. but with your suggestion, I was able to make it work ... even though @egreg's suggestion is clearly superior, for now I will make do with your suggestion. Thanks!